# convergence of $ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{(1+\cos(x))^\alpha} dx $

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I would like to know the necessary and sufficient condition of

$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{(1+\cos(x))^\alpha} dx
$$

converges.

I could prove this diverges when $\alpha \ge 1/2$ ( using Taylor expansion), so I would like to prove it converges when $\alpha$ is smaller than $1/2$.

I recruit good ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only issue is when $x$ is close to $\pi$, and setting $u=\pi-x$, we have that $u^2/2-u^4/4!\leq 1-\cos(u)\leq u^2/2$.  This should be enough to use the comparison test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: $1+\cos x=2\cos^{2}(\frac  x 2)$. Making the substitution $y=\frac x 2$ you end with a constant multiple of $\int_0^{\pi /2} \frac 1 {\cos^{2a}{y}} dy$. Now use the MVT to show that $\cos y=\cos y -\cos {\pi/2} \geq \frac  1 2 (y-\frac {\pi} 2)$ for $y$ near $\pi$.  Now it is easy to finish the proof of convergence for $a <\frac 1  2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formalization of Kavi Rama Murthy's answer.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+\cos(x))^a}
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}x}{2^a\cos^{2a}(x)}\tag1\\
&=2^{1-a}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin^{2a}(x)}\tag2\\
&=2\left[\tfrac12,\tfrac{\pi^2}8\right]_\#^a\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2a}}\tag3\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto2x$
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ apply $1+\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)$
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac\pi2-x$
$(3)$: for $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, $\sin(x)=x\left[\frac2\pi,1\right]_\#$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ where $[a,b]_\#$ represents a number in $[a,b]$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ apply the [Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals)

The integral in $(3)$ converges for $a\lt\frac12$.